# Only @BeforeMethod is getting executed and @Test and @After Method is failing

Tags: selenium, testng

Here is my code:

```
package lowesautomation;

import java.io.File;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class StorePickUP {

public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
      public void beforeMethod() throws Exception {
          WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(); 

             driver.get("http://lwscomsit4.lowes.com/");
             Thread.sleep(10000);
      }

    @Test
      public void Test() throws Exception {
          Thread.sleep(5000);
          driver.findElement(By.id("nav-search-input")).click();
          driver.findElement(By.id("nav-search-input")).sendKeys("29708");
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[4]/form/fieldset/button")).click(); 
          Thread.sleep(8000);
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/ul/li[1]/form/span/input")).sendKeys("138430");
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/ul/li[1]/form/span/button")).click();
        //add to cart
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/form/ul[3]/li[2]/div/a/span")).click();
          driver.navigate().refresh();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("shipModeId_1")).click();
        driver.navigate().refresh();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ShopCartForm']/div[2]/div[2]/a[2]/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-container']/div[2]/div/div/div/a/span")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='checkout-card-type']")).sendKeys("Lowe's consumer credit card");
        driver.findElement(By.name("cardNumber")).sendKeys("81100066123928");
        driver.findElement(By.name("sCode")).sendKeys("686");
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/fieldset/ol/li[4]/div/select[1]")).sendKeys("12-DEC");
      //driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/fieldset/ol/li[4]/div/select[1]")).sendKeys("2015");
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='billingFname']")).sendKeys("chaitra");
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='billingLname']")).sendKeys("aswathanarayana");
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='billingAddress1']")).sendKeys("Test Store Philadelphia");
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='billingCity']")).sendKeys("philadelphia");
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='billingState']")).sendKeys("Pennsylvania");
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='billingZip']")).sendKeys("19114");
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/fieldset/ol/li[2]/div/input")).sendKeys("8105575328");
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/fieldset/ol/li[3]/div/input")).sendKeys("r6sitemail4@lowes.qa");
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[5]/ul/li[3]/a/span")).click();
  }


    @AfterMethod
        public void afterMethod() throws Exception {
            String confno=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='conf-main']/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/strong[2]")).getText();
                System.out.println("confnumber:"+confno);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                    TakesScreenshot ts=(TakesScreenshot)driver;
                    File Source=ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                    FileUtils.copyFile(Source, new File("./screensh/screenshot4.png"));
  }

}
```

I am trying execute the above code in **`TestNG`**, only **`@BeforeMethod`** is getting executed and **`@Test`** and **`@After`** method are failing, can any one please help me on this??

Comment: I tried to execute your code, I received _Access Denied_ error? May be the site is not open to all? Also it will be helpful, if you can post a stacktrace or give details where exactly it is failing .

Comment: insert some assertion inside the BeforeMethod that you can ensure it is ready for testing.

Comment: please change the url to www.lowes.com

Comment: One mistake that you are doing is instead of using `WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(); ` use `driver=new FirefoxDriver(); ` in `BeforeMethod` Because you want to use the driver instance variable and it should be visible in all the methods.  Whats the other error you are getting, can you paste your stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the webdriver from this line in before method, just use driver

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
```

use only

```
 driver=new FirefoxDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

Made changes as below:-

```
WebDriver driver=null;

@BeforeMethod
      public void beforeMethod() throws Exception {
         driver=new FirefoxDriver(); 

         driver.get("http://lwscomsit4.lowes.com/");
         Thread.sleep(10000);
 }
```